# How to detect AngularJS $http errors caused by navigating away from page?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

When making a call with the `$http` service, if the user navigates away from the page while the call is still in progress, it seems the HTTP request is aborted and the promise calls its `error()` handler. However, I can't seem to figure out how to detect when this error is triggered by an actual problem getting a response from the remote server (server down, network down, timeout, etc), versus when the request is simply cancelled because the user navigated. Both cases appear to pass in the same virtually empty response state arguments to the error handler. (`data` is empty, `status` is 0, etc).

I considered using a `beforeUnload` event handler to detect navigation and assume any error encountered after that event should be ignored, however, this event is not supported in mobile Safari and perhaps other browsers, so it's a not a reliable solution.

This seems like it would be a common issue - how are folks generally dealing with it?

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 provides a convenient History API to deal with this kind of situation. However it varies from browser to browser. In order to ensure (up to a point) cross-browser compatibility I'd recommend you to use the library `History.js`.

The library provides a useful event you can handle: `statechange`

For your use case you could warn the user that a request has been initiated and respond to that action accordingly.

https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/

Comment: But will this only detect changes to the location within the current page, e.q. query/hash changes as would be used by in-page ajax app navigation? That would seem to be it's purpose. The issue I have is when the user navigates to a wholly new URL such as an off-site link, my angular app's $http error handler is being called, so the user gets a flash of an error just before they leave the page. FWIW the demo app does not seem to log this kind of navigation, link:  http://browserstate.github.io/history.js/demo/